# Configuring a server that's asking for a hostname?

Tags: networking, vps, hosting

[image]

I'm currently buying a cheap VPS from a provider and I am faced with this input dialogue.
However, I have no idea what these mean as I would of thought they'd of given me an IP of some kind rather than ask for the hostname.
I do have a domain I'd like to use but I'd also like to setup cloudflare and I am unsure as to how to set that up along with this server if it is asking for this if this has anything to do with that.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Honestly, if this page shows up when buying _a VPS_ then I'd be very confused as well. The "hostname" prompt kind of makes sense (rDNS?), the NS (nameserver) prompts just... don't.

Answer (score 0):

If this VM is publicly routable then you can just use your FQDN. This is a normal procedure for example when sending e-mail.

Comment: I asked a friend an he said that it doesn't matter what I enter but I still think there's a reason as to why they're asking this question.